# What causes bright banding in CMOS sensor?

Tags: cmos-image-sensor, banding

The image capturing condition:

1. dark room
2. mobile phone with maximun screen brightness is in the center of the image
3. there is a reddish band in horizontal direction

Does anyone know why the phenomenon appears?

[image]

Comment: What camera and lens are you using?

Answer (score 2):

That is a readout issue that can occur with CMOS sensors.

It is essentially the same thing as CCD "smear;" only in a horizontal direction rather than vertical, and CCD sensors are much more prone to it due to the difference in readout technologies.

It will only occur with a very high contrast source against a very dark BG, and usually only visible with exposure recover/pushing.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by saturation of the sensor. If the pixel well is overloaded, electrons leak in to neighboring pixels which causes the streak. A nice [article](https://www.photometrics.com/learn/imaging-topics/saturation-and-blooming) that has a more in depth explanation.

Comment: That's a problem with CCD sensors.  The article you mention refers to CCD, not CMOS.

Comment: It is not pixel bloom (voltage leaking). And the streak is caused during readout (vertical interline shift w/ CCD, horizontal row readout w/ CMOS)